# Call specific NodeJS function in package.json scripts

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a NodeJS file with an export function a bit like this:

**test.js**

```
exports.run = function(){
  console.log('You run this function!');
};
```

Is there a way to specifically call the function from this file using a custom command in the `scripts` object of `package.json`?

For example, I imagine it would look something like this:

```
{
  "author": "Joe Bloggs",
  "name": "test-app",
  "main": "server.js",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=production node test.js run()",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.10.6",
  }
}
```

Obviously this is the incorrect syntax to run the function.

Comment: Nope. Why do you want to do that? You can actually make it an IIFE and load the module.

Comment: I want to do it so once my app is running, I can call specific tasks by running functions from the terminal, rather than stopping the app

Comment: You can create a JavaScript module on the fly and invoke it with node, if you absolutely have to do so. But that doesn't look like the right way to me

Comment: So if my app is already running, and I want to manually call `require('./test.js').run();` what's the best way to do that?

Comment: @Coop have you tried `node -e "require('./test.js').run();"`

Comment: @Trendfischer no, I'll give that a go. Would there be a way to pass a value to the function when calling it through the terminal like that?

Comment: @Coop perhaps this https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#special-package-json-config-object or https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env if you like to use environment variables like in your example

Answer (score 11):

You could use a good ol' switch case and pass arguments to your script.

**test.js**

```
function foo(){
  console.log('foo is called');
}

function bar(){
  console.log('bar is called');
}

for (var i=0; i<process.argv.length;i++) {
  switch (process.argv[i]) {
    case 'foo':
      foo();
      break;
    case 'bar':
      bar();
      break;
  }
}

module.exports.foo = foo;
module.exports.bar = bar;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "author": "A person",
  "name": "test-app",
  "main": "server.js",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=production node test.js foo bar"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.10.6"
  }
}
```

test.js:foo() and test.js:bar() will now be called by npm test. You can also require it like you normally would.
This answers your question, but your later comments made me unsure if this is what you're after.

Comment: if `foo` will get a parameter like: function foo(test){
  console.log('foo is called + text');
} , how in this case to eun foo here ` "test": "NODE_ENV=production node test.js foo bar"
  },`?